# Kotlin switch-statement with more than two variables?

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin

Say I set getCount() = 3, how can I specify which fragment and page title to retrieve for the third item?

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
        override fun getCount() = 3
        override fun getItem(i: Int) = if (i == 0) KotlinListFragment() else if (i == 1) JavaListFragment() else (i == 2) AndroidFragment()
        override fun getPageTitle(i: Int) = if (i == 0) "Kotlin" else (i == 1) "Java" else (i == 2) "Android"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

```
when (getCount()) {
   0 -> return "a"
   1 -> return "b"
   2 -> return "c"
   else -> return "" 
}
```

or

```
return when (getCount()) {
   0 -> "a"
   // etc
   else -> ""
}
```

or

```
when (getCount()) {

   0 -> {
   // do something here
   }
   // etc.
   else -> {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't what you were really asking but it might actually be easier to have a Paired List and do normal index retrieval instead. For example

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
    private val fragment = listOf("Kotlin" to KotlinListFragment(),
        "Java" to JavaListFragment(),
        "Android" to AndroidFragment())

    override fun getCount() = 3
    override fun getItem(i: Int) = fragment[i].second()
    override fun getPageTitle(i: Int) = fragment[i].first()
}
```

It looks like you control count range but assuming you don't you can also compare the i to the length of the list and if greater then length use the length instead. That should easily handle your "two variable" scenario in a fairly manageable way I think.